# BSD netcat with file init, stdin and graceful shutdown

Tags: bash, netcat, bsd

I am using BSD `netcat` and trying to write a utility script that:

1. Connects to a HAProxy port
2. Automatically feeds it with the Proxy Protocol Header (`PROXY TCP4`)
3. Then reads input from `stdin`
4. Ends the prompt when the connection is closed remotely

I've got steps 1 to 3 done by using the `cat file - | nc` syntax, e.g:

```
echo "PROXY TCP4 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 8080 80" > header_file
cat header_file - | nc host port
```

The issue with this approach is that the prompt will remain opened after the connection is closed by the server. Ending the prompt requires the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

How can change this tiny script to do the line feeding + stdin + automatically end the prompt when the connection is closed?

Comment: What is the output like when the connection is closed?

Comment: No output. The connection is closed gracefully by the server. netcat itself detects the connection and closes it client side gracefully as well (tested by not using the cat part of the command, netcat itself ends the prompt).

Comment: There is a timeout option in netcat which you could try adding `-w0`

Comment: An Expect script might be a better way to do this.